# Making a PreferenceFragmentCompat Settings screen load faster (Navigation UI)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, preload

Refering to this Settings Screen: (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings)

I've noticed a small lag when changing to the settings screen, which doesn't happen when changing to other fragments (when using a Navigation UI controlled Bottom Navigation Bar). I believe this is caused because the preferences xml file is loaded in a fragment at run time, since after changing fragments the lag goes out. Also this lag doesn't occur when changing to the other fragments.

This is my main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    NavController navController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);  
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

    }
}
```

The settings fragment

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottomNavColor"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_view"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_screen" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Bottom Navigation Manu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_fragment_main"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_dark"
        android:title="Home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="My Profile" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="Settings" />
</menu>
```

nav_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_fragment_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_fragment_main"
        android:name="com.example.drinkinggamesapp.Fragment_main"
        android:label="fragment_main_screen"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_screen" >
    </fragment>
    
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.drinkinggamesapp.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="SettingsFragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.example.drinkinggamesapp.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
</navigation>
```

How could I reduce the lag when changing to the Settings Fragment? Can I somehow preload it and keep the NavigationUI? Anyone got experience with it?